# Converse to a proposition regarding topology and the continuum hypothesis.

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I read in a book that a particular topological statement, which I will call $T$, implies the negation of the continuum hypothesis. $T$ is this statement: "In every compact Hausdorff topological space satisfying the countable chain condition, the intersection of $\aleph_1$ dense open sets is nonempty". I am now wondering if the converse is true. That is, if the cardinality of the continuum is at least $\aleph_2$, must $T$ hold? Or is there a model of $ZFC$ set theory where the continuum is at least $\aleph_2$, but $T$ is false?

Comment: No, you're looking at Martin's Axiom type situation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Asaf said in his comment, this is a Martin's Axiom type situation. To be more precise, this is MA at $\omega_1$. In general, $MA(\kappa)$ is equivalent to

- In every ccc compact Hausdorff space $X$, fewer than $\kappa$ many closed nowhere dense sets cannot cover $X$.

Or taking complements,

- In every ccc compact Hausdorff space $X$, fewer than $\kappa$ many open dense sets must have a nonempty intersection.

Comment: But that doesn't answer my question of whether the negation of the continuum hypothesis implies my statement.

Comment: No it doesn't. It is consistent with not CH that the least $\kappa$ where Martin's Axiom holds is greater than $\omega_1$.